# How do I Control Which Desktop C++ Graphics Output to on Raspberry Pi?

Tags: c++, raspberry-pi, vnc

I am trying to run a programming club in my school and it's not practical to physically connect the Pi's to kb, mouse and monitor so they all auto-run VNC and we connect to the machines using Ultra-VNC. The programs are written in a shared directory and Eclipse C++ runs on the host; therefore all program output is viewed via VNC.

Everything was fine while programming in Python and when we started to use C++.  However, I hit a  brik wall when trying to get graphics to display.  I could build a program that appeared to run, but which only gave terminal output - it would never display drawings on the screen.  While trying to solve the problem and at one point connected a keyboard and mouse and noticed that they seemed to be recognised (laser came on, Caps Lock toggled, etc.) but they didn't do anything when moved/typed on.

Eventually the penny began to teater on the edge as I got increasingly confused as to why no one else was having this problem given that there seem to be a lot of people using openvg and I began to wonder more about the kb/mouse issue.

I tried plugging the HDMI output into a monitor at home (shool ones are still analogue d-sub!) and lo and behold, the physical kb and mouse worked. Then it got really strange!

Somehow I have 2 desktops running at the same time. The physical keyboard and mouse control one and VNC controls the other.  If I start a terminal window on 'Physical' desktop, it doesn't show up on 'VNC' desktop and vice versa - they seem to be independent, although that's not quite true.

When I run the graphics executable on 'Physical' desktop, it works fine and can be controlled only using the physical kb. When I run it on 'VNC' desktop, it can be controlled only with the VNC kb but the output displays on the physical screen.

I really don't get this!

I kind of need to be able to run the programs over VNC, but I need to be able to tell the code I run which desktop to output to as it seems to default to the wrong one.  Actually, it would be prefferable to get VNC to connect to the existing HDMI desktop rather than starting a new one but I cannot findout how to tell tightVNC to do that.

The code is here, but I think the problem might be in the init() function which is in a library, so it is probably better to get VNC on to the right desktop...

Thanks in advance for any help!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

extern "C" {
#include "VG/openvg.h"
#include "VG/vgu.h"
#include "fontinfo.h"
#include "shapes.h"
}

using namespace std;

int main (void) {

int width, height;
        VGfloat w2, h2, w;
    char s[3];

    init(&width, &height);                                      // Graphics initialization

    w2 = (VGfloat)(width/2);
    h2 = (VGfloat)(height/2);
    w  = (VGfloat)w;

    Start(width, height);                                       // Start the picture
    Background(0, 0, 0);                                        // Black background
    Fill(44, 77, 232, 1);                                       // Big blue marble
    Circle(w2, 0, w);                                           // The "world"
    Fill(255, 255, 255, 1);                                     // White text
    TextMid(w2, h2, "hello, world", SerifTypeface, width/10);   // Greetings
    End();                                                      // End the picture
    fgets(s, 2, stdin);                                         // Pause until RETURN]
    finish();                                                   // Graphics cleanup
    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Found a closed Stack Overflow thread that suggested changing the res of VNC to match that of the HDMI desktop.  Tried this, but VNC choked on the color depth and trying to set the screen res nearly borked my install - LXDE crashed on start up and had to find how to boot to terminal - actually, don't think I ever did, I think the CTRL+ALT+F1 forced a command line to open or something similar... Close escape, don't think that's going to work...

Comment: **Update**

Ok,  Feeling a bit disheartened but it is a programming problem.

Installed Vino, which got me to see the 'physical desktop' over VNC.  Could see and manipulate it but shapesdemo still only displays on the HDMI connection not over VNC.

Not even sure where to go from here as I can definitly see the desktop that has the mouse and keyboard attached and so I must be seeing the place where the graphics are appearing.  They are just missing from what is sent across VNC.

Is there any way of overcoming this?

Other apps are not invisibe over VNC!

Comment: Random thought: Is it because something is created in the command line?  If I run shapesdemo from the GUI, nothing appears either (i.e. on the Physical Desktop).

Is there some way of making the built file display when run from the GUI? And will that output then go over VNC?

Comment: Aparently both tightVMC and vino use x windows and the pi bypasses this and draws directly on the screen via the GPU with open VG, so you can't look at openvg over VNC...

Answer (score 0):

See last comment - abandoned openvg and using X Windows.